# Putting LaTeX Equations in MS Word

Tags: texlive, msword, embedding, ghostscript

I want to put LaTeX equations in MS Word 2010. @Werner suggested IguanaTeX to convert it in PowerPoint then paste it into Word. I downloaded and installed the plug-in, but I keep getting this error message every time I try to run it:

[image]

I also installed `TeX Live` and `GhostScript` but I honestly have no idea what this error means (in spite of Google searching for hours) or how to fix it. Any and all help is welcome.

Comment: It seems to look for `pdflatex` executable in `PATH` and not finding it. That would be my guess.

Comment: Just curious. Why not using equation tool in Word? Because you want to re-use the existing LaTeX equation?

Comment: @wilx How do I move `pdflatex` to `PATH`?

Comment: @watchTower: I do not remember exactly but I think your TeX Live installation should do it automatically. I would try first with reinstalling TeX Live maybe. If that fails to introduce the changes, look at [How do I set or change the PATH system variable?](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) for a guide.

Comment: Have you tried writing the equations in LaTeX using the "standalone" format and then inserting the PDF of the equation into the Word file?